# Event delegation failing due to difference in targeted element between browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

This is a simplified excerpt from the DOM:

```
<td>
    <button value="11" class="expand ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" title="">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

This is repeated for every row in the table (~500), and the table has an ID of 'eventTable'

Here's the button instantiation (jQueryUI):

```
$('.expand').each(function(){
    $(this).button({
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-plus"
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a part of the event delegation on table #eventTable

```
$('#eventTable').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('.expand'){
        // ...
```

Now, in Firefox 3.6.x, IE7,8, this works and steps into the `if` statement. In Safari and Chrome, however, `e.target` represents the first `span` instead of the surrounding `button`.

Why is this happening? I can work past it, but I would love an explanation so I don't run into the same problem later in a different scenario. Why is Webkit right and Trident/Gecko wrong? What caused the difference?

Comment: I have trouble believing that e.target is the first span and that checking $(e.target).parent() doesn't do what you want.  Those seem incompatible.

Comment: You're right. Just switched from IDE to Vim -- tested an out-of-date file. Editing...

Comment: Why don't you just put a click event on the button itself?

Comment: It's probably not it, but suddenly `capture` and `bubble` just popped into my mind.

Comment: @DarthJDG Because I have ~500 buttons. I don't want to create a click event for each one -- that's wasted memory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you use `.delegate()`, that's not going to create ~500 distinct click event handlers, but rather just one on the context. Every time a click goes off on the context, it'll check your selector if it matches, and fire off the handler if it does. You could try `$('#eventTable').delegate('click','.expand',function(){});` and that should work wonderfully.

Comment: @richardneililagan You're correct. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Posting my comment as an answer.*

If you're just wary not to get a ton of `click` handler references on your DOM, I'd suggest you use `.delegate()` instead. It "binds" only one handler onto a context, and checks if the event target matches a selector you provide, and fires off the handler if it does.

Something like

```
$('#eventTable').delegate('click', '.expand', function() {
    // click on the .expand element/s
});
```

should suffice.